# Live-USB does not run sudo apt-get update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, live-usb

I have a dual boot with Ubuntu 16.04 and Win10.
Due to some issues, I was trying to fix some problems that didn't make Ubuntu to boot. Then I ended up with a grub that doesn't work properly, so that when I power on the laptop, no dual-boot options appear, and Windows is booted automatically.

Therefore, I was trying [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) with a Live Usb, but the *sudo apt-get update* command returns the following:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial InRelease
Hit:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719) xenial Release
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                          
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]      
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu xenial InRelease [17.5 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [95.7 kB]        
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1,864 B]
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en [2,092 B]
Fetched 212 kB in 0s (449 kB/s)                                      

** (appstreamcli:9435): CRITICAL **: Error while moving old database out of the way.
AppStream cache update failed.
Reading package lists... Done
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: You are installing these in the Ram, as soon as you reboot your computer it will be lost anyway, it won't affect the Ubuntu installation you have on your disk.

Comment: @MuaadElSharif, thanks! So how can I fix the grub to have my dual-boot back?

Comment: @Py-ser You can use the Boot Repair own live disk instead: https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/ . However, the "repair" may or may not work depending on the specific problem. The discussion in your other question suggests it happened after a UEFI reset.

Comment: @CelticWarrior, thank you! So what would you recommend to do?

Comment: Type in this command in the terminal `sudo update-grub`

Comment: @MuaadElSharif, I managed to fix the grub. Indeed there was no need to update apt-get: from the Live USB it was simply a matter of updating the grub.

Comment: Since my answer helped you, please mark it as the solution to close the question, not the comment! The answer below :)

Comment: @MuaadElSharif, thanks! However, your answer does not answer the question. I can still accept the answer (although I found it by myself before, but I don't care), I would be happy to do that, but if you could add something about the original problem it would be the best for future reference.

Comment: What did  you find on your own that you want me to add to my answer for you to accept it?

Comment: How to run run sudo apt-get update, or how to solve the 'appstreamcli' error that it gives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to update the apt-get in live mode.

You are installing these in the Ram, as soon as you reboot your computer it will be lost anyway, it won't affect the Ubuntu installation you have on your disk.

Type in this command in the terminal `sudo update-grub`

to fix your problem.